# Android Chrome large font bug/zoom bug/meta viewport device-width not working

Tags: android, css, google-chrome

I'm having a difficult time with a mobile site I'm creating.

Everything is working as expected on all of the devices I've tested, and all of the different mobile browsers I've tested, aside from one: Chrome (v38.x) on Android (Nexus 7)

Essentially, what is happening is that everything is seems to be blown up/zoomed in, and it's making the site layout look ridiculous.

I'm using the meta viewport tag and em-based media queries to show different layouts depending on the device.

Here is a very simple example of what's happening:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;initial-scale=1.0;" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="top">Font size: 1em</div>
</body>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t6fdb3ak/3/

And below is a screenshot of how this displays on the Android Chrome browser.

[image: Android Chrome font size bug]

This seems absolutely wacky, why is this happening?

Also, if I alert the innerWidth of the window on this page, I'm getting 121px instead of 980px.

```
<script>
    alert(window.innerWidth);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem after reading some of this page https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/pixelperfect

I removed the semi-colons from the viewport meta tag, and replaced them with commas, like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This is how it looked before:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;initial-scale=1.0;" />
```

Hopefully everything will still work in the other browsers. I'll report back if not!

Answer (score -4):

Try to import bootstrap, They have a build in viewport, if you use that it will work for sure.